# Do I have to handle all input types to pass Windows Store Certification?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have a game that I'm porting to the Windows Store, but unfortunately, the game genre doesn't really work well with touch input. I currently support keyboard, mouse, and gamepad, but I'm worried that I will get rejected because I don't handle touch.

Anyone have experience with this or know where I can look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here: [Windows 8 app certification requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694083.aspx)

> 3.5 Your app must fully support touch input, and fully support keyboard and mouse input
>
> Your app must provide visual feedback when users touch interactive
>   elements.

Which is a bummer because now I'm not sure how one can publish a game to the store that just doesn't make sense with touch input.

Comment: While they might mention something like that - all of the apps I published don't make sense to use with keyboard, so perhaps that rule is more of a guideline, though I would say some simple touch input should work in any app or game unless your app is a console window, but then still you could touch the console to move the cursor or select the text, so no. I think touch should be usable in any app. Keyboard - not necessarily alone, but with mouse - it should work.

Comment: Filip, I agree that touch can work in menus, but during the game, mine just wouldn't work well at all with touch. I'll try to see how things work out when I finally submit.

Comment: Good luck! I agree that touch might not work as well as keyboard+mouse in many scenarios, but making it at least possible with these should be doable.